# How to convert a list of dictionaries inside a tuple into pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and want to know how to convert list of dict inside a tuple into a dataframe.

I tried following but nothing worked as I wanted

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pair)
df1= pd.DataFrame.from_records(pair)


    Input
    data = [({'Column1': 'US1',
       'Column2': '44',
       'Column3': 'ABC123',
       'Column4': '25/02/19',
       'Column5': 2200.0},
      {'Column1': 'US1',
       'Column2': '44',
       'Column3': 'XYZ123',
       'Column4': '13/01/19',
       'Column5': 1061.0})]

        Output:
        Column1    Column2     Column3    Column4      Column5
        US1         44          ABC123     25/02/19     2200.0
        US1         44          XYZ123     13/01/19     1061.0
```

Thanks in advance

Edited:

Thanks alot it worked. Have one more question. 
I am trying to add a new key to the above input list of dict inside a tuple using update({'key' : keyvalue} ). But it doesn't seem to work.

Want something like this where I added NewColumn : NewValue

```
data = 
[({'Column1': 'US1', 
'Column2': '44', 
'Column3': 'ABC123', 
'Column4': '25/02/19', 
'Column5': 2200.0, 
**'NewColumn': 'NewValue**}, 
{'Column1': 'US1', 
'Column2': '44', 
'Column3': 'XYZ123', 
'Column4': '13/01/19', 
'Column5': 1061.0 , 
**'NewColumn': 'NewValue**})]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra unwanted layer of wrapping on your data: the tuple is inside a list.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(data[0])
  Column1 Column2 Column3   Column4  Column5
0     US1      44  ABC123  25/02/19   2200.0
1     US1      44  XYZ123  13/01/19   1061.0
```

Comment: Thanks alot it worked. Have one more question. I am trying to add a new key to the above input list of dict inside a tuple using update({'key' : keyvalue} ). But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: data = [({'Column1': 'US1',
       'Column2': '44',
       'Column3': 'ABC123',
       'Column4': '25/02/19',
       'Column5': 2200.0,                                                                                                     
       'NewColumn': 'NewValue},
      {'Column1': 'US1',
       'Column2': '44',
       'Column3': 'XYZ123',
       'Column4': '13/01/19',
       'Column5': 1061.0 ,                                                                                                     
       'NewColumn': 'NewValue})]

Comment: You would need to update each dict separately (perhaps using a loop), and if you want that reflected in your DataFrame then you would have to do it before creating the DataFrame. Better idea is to use Pandas stuff directly at that point to add a new column.